# How good is linux encrypted file system?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, hard-drive, encryption

I am using xubuntu 12 . I just used palimpsest to encrypt my external harddisk and it seems cool. But I am wondering how easy it is for someone to crack my harddisk using any tools available. And one more thing, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage asks us to do the following commands to make cracking difficult.

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4K
 OR
 sudo badblocks -c 10240 -s -w -t random -v /dev/sdb
 OR
 sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=4K
```

So can this be done after I have created the encrypted partition. Like My device is `sdb` and the encrypted partition is `sdb1`.

so how should I go about these commands.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4K
```

And how does random, or adding zero makes it difficult to crack.

Answer (score 0):

The zero and then random is to make it more difficult to determine where there is data, since the encrypted filesystem (if working correctly) is indistinguishable from noise. No, you cannot run those commands after you have the filesystem created (unless you will then re-install); if you do, then the system is slightly more secure then it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

You ask "But I am wondering how easy it is for someone to crack my harddisk using any tools available."  I remember reading about someone who refused to hand over their password to a court and got locked up for contempt.  The police decrypted the drives not long after.  From that press report I assume no encryption is foolproof.

You have to think about what you are protecting and from what.  Protecting your bank details from a thief who will sell your computer for drugs, then any simple encryption will do the job.  If you are working for Mr. Al Kieda or you are another Terry Wrist then I doubt the encryption methods available will do any good when you get a knock on the door.

No one is going to tell you what encryption methods they can or can not crack.